determinant of a matrix of linear forms
Suppose $R=k[x_1,\dots,x_d]$ and $M$ is a $n\times n$ matrix with entries which are linear in $R$. If $\det M=0$, can we say that one row (or column) can be written as a $k$-linear combination of the other rows (columns)? Assume $d\geq 3,n\geq 3$ and there is no row or column of zeroes in $M$.

No. E.g. let $k$ be any field and
$$
M=\pmatrix{x_1&x_1&x_1\\ x_2&x_2&x_2\\ x_3&x_4&x_5}.
$$
As the first two rows of $M$ are linearly dependent (with $x_2M_{1\ast}-x_1M_{2\ast}=0$), $M$ has a zero determinant. However, no row of $M$ is a $k$-linear combination of the others because each row of $M$ contains an indeterminate that is not contained in any other row. The similar can also be said about the columns of $M$.

Thanks a lot for the example. Is there a way to characterize $\det M=0$. Can we say something about the columns or rows of $M$ in this case?

@dongrugose I only know the trivial criterion. If $k$ is a field, then $R$ is an integral domain. Therefore $\det M=0$ if and only if some row/column of $M$ is an $R$-linear combination of the others.

Thanks! I forgot to add that $k$ is a field. Can you give a reference for this?

@dongrugose If you mean the statement that “$R=k[x_1,\ldots,x_d]$ is an integral domain when $k$ is a field”, this is mentioned (if not proved) in most books on abstract algebra. The proof is utterly simple. See Proof Wiki for instance. If you mean the statement that “$\det M=0$ iff its columns are linearly dependent over (the integral domain) $R$”, I don’t know any reference but this is just a direct consequence of the fact that $\det M=0$ iff its columns are linearly dependent over the field of fractions of $R$.
